# How to insert large protein sequences in a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, bioinformatics

I am creating a protein database, which consists of large protein sequences. I have created four tables, one of which stores genomeID, sequenceID, name, and sequence. I can easily store other values using INSERT INTO command MySQL, but I am struck in inserting these large protein sequences in fasta format because one genome has thousands of peptide sequences.
I want to figure out a way where I can store these sequences using MySQL.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Please, read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 even though your question **seems like** conceptual the given link is a good start on how to explain the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that genomes contain several billions of characters it isn't feasible to store this in a sql database because even the longest data type can at most hold around 1000 characters. Instead what I would recommend is using a NoSQL key-value db to store your sequences.